# In Excel, Why does the same script run slower using activex button? Can it be faster?

Tags: excel, vba

I put together this macro that simply generates data

```
Sub GenerateData()
    For curRow = 5 To 100 Step 1
        For curCol = 1 To 40 Step 1
            Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = curRow * curCol
        Next curCol
    Next curRow
End Sub
```

When I assign it to an excel userform button, it performs the script seemingly instantly, however when I assign it to an activex button it performs at a speed my eyes can follow.

Why do script run under ActiveX run slower? and can a simple O(mn) script run faster using ActiveX buttons?

I could improve the script with loop unrolling, but is it necessary or are there other approaches for speeding it up?

Comment: You could do the whole thing with one line: `Range("A5:AN100") = [Index(Row(A5:AN100)*Column(A5:AN100),0)]` And not matter how it is called it would be nearly instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A viable solution, other than converting it to a one line statement as Scott suggested, apparently was setting the calculation to xl manual at the beginning of the code then setting it back to automatic at the end. This is because each time a single cell changes, excel worksheet recalculates for the entire worksheet. So by setting it to manual prior to script, you're telling it to wait to recalculate until everything has been generated.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

[code]

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```